# How do I decompress a zstd compressed payload in scala

Tags: scala, compression, zstd

Hi I have a payload that i need to decompress in scala

```
val uncompressed = "" //payload to be decompressed
val uncomprBytes = uncompressed.getBytes()
val size =  uncomprBytes.length
val decompressedStr = decompress(uncomprBytes,size)
```

and I'm getting following error -

```
Exception in thread "main" com.github.luben.zstd.ZstdException: Unknown frame descriptor
    at com.github.luben.zstd.ZstdDecompressCtx.decompressByteArray(ZstdDecompressCtx.java:157)
    at com.github.luben.zstd.ZstdDecompressCtx.decompress(ZstdDecompressCtx.java:214)
    at com.github.luben.zstd.ZstdDecompressCtx.decompress(ZstdDecompressCtx.java:219)
    at com.github.luben.zstd.Zstd.decompress(Zstd.java:1067)
```

I have read that there is chance payload string is missing the header data in such error..
If that's the case please let me know how to add header to payload string.

Comment: you might need to add you build.sbt definition to exact

Comment: I'm using maven to build the jar.. do you mean I need to add it's pom/xml?

Comment: this would help to replicate issue

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to decompress not compressed bytes?